# how to make custom directive in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make custom directive in angular .I try to add input field in my view when I click on button .In other words I am trying to make one custom directive in which when user press the button it add one input field in the browser .I think it is too easy if I am not use custom directive   Mean If I use only controller then I take one array and push item in array when user click on button and button click is present on controller.

But when  need to make custom  directive where I will write my button click event in controller or directive

here is my code
http://play.ionic.io/app/23ec466dac1d

```
   angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('appcontrl',function($scope){

  $scope.data=[]
}).directive('inputbutton',function(){
  return {

    restrict :'E',
    scope:{
      data:'='
    },
    template:'<button>Add input</button> <div ng-repeat="d in data"><input type="text"></div>',
    link:function(s,e,a){
      e.bind('click',function(){
        s.data.push({})
      })

    }

  }

})
```

I just need to add input field when user click on button using custom directive ..could you please tell me where i am doing wrong ?

**can we make button template and click event inside the directive**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because your registering your click handler with jQuery. So when the click handler fires it is out of the scope of angular so angular does not know it needs to update its bindings.

So you have two options, the first is to tell angular in the click handler, 'yo buddy, update your bindings'. this is done using `$scope.$apply`

$apply docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

```
        e.bind('click',function(){
            s.$apply(function() {
                s.data.push({});
            });
        });
```

However angular already has built in directive for handling things like mouse clicks you can just use that and let angular do the work for you. This would be the better option.

so first in your view register a click handler on your button

```
<button ng-click="add()">Add input</button> <div ng-repeat="d in data"><input type="text"></div>
```

Then in your link simply add the `add()` method of your scope

```
        s.add = function () {
            s.data.push({});
        }
```

Heres a working fiddle showing both examples. http://jsfiddle.net/3dgdrvkq/

---

EDIT: Also noticed a slight bug in your initial click handler. You registering a click but not specifying the button to apply it to. So if you clicked anywhere in the directive, not just the button, the handler would fire. You should be more specific when registering events manually, using ids, class names attributes etc.

The `e` or `element` property of the link function is a jqlite or full jQuery object of the entire directive. If you have jQuery included before angular it will be a full jQuery object. If not it will a jqlite object. A thinned out version of jQuery.

Comment: strictly speaking this is not jquery, but jquery light that angular uses by default. rest is true

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example for your logic .

```
  var TestApp = angular.module('App', []);
```

// controller

```
TestApp.controller('mainCtrl', function mainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.data = [];
   $scope.addDataItem = function () {
   $scope.data.push({
        someFilield: 'some value'
    });
    console.log('pushing value ... ');
   }
});
```

// view

```
 <div ng-app="App" class="container" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <button type="button" ng-click="addDataItem()">Add an input</button>
   <div ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">
     <custom-directive model="d"></custom-directive>
   </div>
 </div>
```

// directive

```
  TestApp.directive('customDirective', function customDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        model: '='
      },
      template: 'item -> <input type = "text" />',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log('scope.model', scope.model);
      },
      controller: function ($scope) {
        // do staff here
      }
   }
 });
```

Comment: please provide play ionic

Comment: @user944513 what you mean saying " provide play ionic " ?

Comment: please provide plunker or fiddle or playionic

Comment: can we add click event on directive ? can we make damo using only directive not using controller ?

Comment: can we make button template and click eveny inside the template

Comment: sure just move `Add input` button to you directive template and `addDataItem` to directive controller also `ng-repeat`